# Angular directive works only the first time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have created amCharts directive which somehow works only first time, the second time doesn't show up until i clear browser cache.
Another problem is that it only works in Chrome :/

Here is my code:

```
.directive('amGraph', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
            scope: {
            getArchiveData: '='
        },
        template: '<div id="chartdiv"></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs){

            scope.$watch('getArchiveData', function(data){

                 var chart = false;

                 var initChart = function(){
                     if (chart) chart.destroy();

                     chart = new AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
                          ...
                     });
                 };

                 initChart();

            });
        }
     }
 })
```

This is HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="dataCtrl">
<am-graph get-archive-data="getData"></am-graph>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show this issue in Fiddle? why  you dont use isolate scope?

Comment: From what you presented here it does not seem to be an angular issue.

Comment: @MaximShoustin why should i use isolate scope?

Comment: @arturgrzesiak Then what is? :D

Comment: I'm trying now with isolate scope.

Comment: @MaximShoustin Same thing even with isolated scope. :(

Comment: @user3523219 did you try to reproduce the issue in Plunker/Fiddle?

Comment: @MaximShoustin I have updated my question, do you have any clues from this? I will try to reproduce error in jsfiddle.

Comment: The reason is pretty clear: the `$watch` fired only once. I answered on day on one of your questions, please take a look on this example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9YnpS/43/

Comment: @MaximShoustin Yes, i have seen that example many times, still it doesn't make much sense. I have updated my question using logic from jsfiddle link which still doesn't work. If for you the reason is pretty clear please explain me because i really have no more ideas how to solve it. Because after reading angular docs, code inside $watch should be fired on every attribute change which works well the first time, in console log i recorded it was fired twice, which means it works. But after i reload the page nothing happends.
Please have patince with me, you all started with this errors :)

Comment: please, reproduce it in fiddle.

Comment: @MaximShoustin Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4eAx/ It's the same code i'm using except that controller gets data from factory. As i mentioned before, works only chrome, but in jsfiddle also has problems.

Comment: if you get data from factory (async way) did you try to invoke `$apply` to launch additional digest cycle?

Comment: I tried adding: scope.$apply() after $watch but still no luck.

Comment: Intheresting problem, if reload page with button "reload" the graph will show, if hit enter on url bar it won't. And that's in all browsers. I think it's not directive at all. "Maybe" it's RequireJS.

Comment: And now it's working after i removed $apply. I have no idea what was nor why is working now, really. Big thanks @MaximShoustin for helping me out. I only wish to know why and how happened this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It works in here: http://jsfiddle.net/tkX89/ may be you are writing your HTML wrong. No issue with angular.

although for tip:

```
replace: true
```

will replace your directive tag with template assigned. Be careful with that.

PS: using factory for getting data is awesome. Keep on the track!!

Comment: I don't think it could be an HTML problem. Directive work perfectly well first time, after i reload the page doesn't show up without any errors. Thanks for help :)